# Where should ModelState.Clear be called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which open in a pop-up and user can save or cancel/close the form. I need suggestion that where should i clear model? In GET method or in POST method? Usually i have doing in post method but in this scenario, if user open a form and then close the pop-up, it means execution will not go to post method and model will not be cleared if i use in Post method. So what is the best way to do this ?

Currently, I am doing this:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult AddEditForm(long id, int number = 0)
 {
     ModelState.Clear();
     var entity = new coll().getbyidandnumber(id,number);

     return PartialView(entity)
 }
```

Is this a right way or not?

Comment: Good question. I think you should use in GET method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Waiting for more suggestions.

Comment: @Umer: depends on the situation, but it will clear all error validation messages in your model. if you call Clear like in your example, if user open popup, you will lost all validation messages and the system will think your model is valid even though it's not (assume you have some errors in model). Normally, I would not call Clear method manually unless I want to force the data to be valid anyhow.

Comment: +1 for answer. Agreed, all validation will be lost. Actually, this form can open again and again.That's why Model.Clear() is necessary.

Comment: Can you explain your business scenario? Why do you want to clear ModelState Errors?

Comment: @Umer Do you still have this problem?

Comment: @SuperCoder Nope. My problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Umer! Great. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

It will clear your all error validation messages, your text-boxes data and it also loose selected drop downs values.